# Type mismatch when setting up pivotcache

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have pCach as PivotCache

when I just do

```
ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=pTRng).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:= _
    wOPT.Cells(3, 1), TableName:="PivotTable2")
```

It works as expected and inserts pivotcache on the destination cell

But when I try this it gives me type mismatch error?

```
 Set pCach = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=pTRng).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:= _
    wOPT.Cells(3, 1), TableName:="PivotTable2")
```

Comment: how did you  `Dim pCach` ?

Comment: @iDevlop `Dim pCach As PivotCache`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try splitting setting the `PivotCache` and the `PivotTable` to 2 seperate code lines, like in the code below :

```
Dim pTbl  As PivotTable
Dim pCach As PivotCache

' set the Pivot Cache
Set pCach = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=pTRng)

' create a new Pivot Table in "wOPT" sheet, start from Cell A3
Set pTbl = wOPT.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=pCach, TableDestination:=wOPT.Range("A3"), TableName:="PivotTable2")
```

Comment: Yes I tried it says I have to wait 1 minute more before I can mark it as an answer.

Comment: Yes we have to wait for 5 minutes after the answer has been posted before we can accept it as solution if I am not wrong.