# VBA Code to Create Pivot Table Was Working, Now it is Not

Tags: vba, caching, pivot

Any help would be appreciated.  The Code below was working previously, now it is not.  I have the exact same code for a different PIVOT table down below this one and it works perfectly.  I'm scratching my head on this one.

```vb
'Pivot Tables
Sub TestPivot()

    Sheets("Reported Sales").Select
 
'Declare Variables

    Dim PSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DSheet As Worksheet
    Dim PCache As PivotCache
    Dim PTable As PivotTable
    Dim PRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long


'Declare Variables

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("Pivot Reported Sales").Delete
    Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Pivot Reported Sales"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Set PSheet = Worksheets("Pivot Reported Sales")
    Set DSheet = Worksheets("Reported Sales")

'Define Data Range

    LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

'Define Pivot Cache

    Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
    (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
    TableName:="Pivot Reported Sales")

'Insert Blank Pivot Table

    Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
    (TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), TableName:="Pivot Reported Sales")

'Insert Row Fields

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot Reported Sales").PivotFields("PROD_BASE_CD")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
    End With
    
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot Reported Sales").PivotFields("Product Description")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot Reported Sales").PivotFields("Compensation Category")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 3
    End With

'Insert Data Field

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot Reported Sales").PivotFields("PROD_SALES_AMT")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 1
    .Function = xlSum
    .NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot Reported Sales").PivotFields("INVC_DATE")
            .Orientation = xlPageField
            .Position = 1
    End With
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type mismatch when setting up pivotcache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41591111/type-mismatch-when-setting-up-pivotcache)

Comment: Remove the `.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
TableName:="Pivot Reported Sales")` in `Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
TableName:="Pivot Reported Sales")`

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Tried it but still receiving Run Time Error 440.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with the revised code and note which line throws the error?

Comment: Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
    (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

Comment: Per above instruction I removed .CreatePivotTable, etc.  This is where I'm receiving the error.  Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
    (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
    TableName:="Pivot Reported Sales")